# Create an android app shortcut without asking `add to home screen`permission popup

Tags: android, shortcut

Is it possible to add an android app shortcut in home screen launcher without asking permission popup.

I tried but couldn't find any information/documentation.

Even tried with reflection but it is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Since Android asking for permissions to do certain stuff, such as changing home screen and accessing contacts is a safety feature of Android, I am almost certain that it is impossible for an app to avoid this.

The only exception I can think of is Google Play Store, which is built into Android so it makes sense that it is an exception.